# Evaluating a colimit of functors

Tags: category-theory

This is my first question here. I am working on some categories and this question regarding functors seemed very natural:

Let $\{G_\alpha \rightarrow F\}_{\alpha \in \Gamma}$ with $F$ and $\{G_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \Gamma} $ functors in $Sets^{C}$ be an universal cone, i.e., $F = co\varinjlim_{\alpha\in \Gamma}    \ G_\alpha$, and $\Gamma$ a filtered category. Then is it true that

$F(C) = co\varinjlim_{\alpha\in \Gamma}    \ G_\alpha(C)$ ?

I am not asking for a solution just a general tip to solve it! Thanks :)

Comment: Hints: It makes no difference that $\Gamma$ is filtered. You could get a very nice argument using the fact that maps $F\to G$ of functors are a certain equalizer contained in the product $\prod_{c\in C} Sets(F(c),G(c))$ of hom-sets. If you don't like that, I don't really see any tips, without you having shown any of your own efforts-just write down exactly what each universal property says.

Comment: I proved that $G_\alpha (C) \xrightarrow{\lambda_\alpha (C)} F(C)$, where $\lambda_\alpha$ is the N.T of the cone, is a cone, and that given another cone $G_\alpha(C) \xrightarrow{\mu_\alpha} H$, there exists an arrow $F(C) \rightarrow H$, using the universal property of the colimit for the cone $G_\alpha  \xrightarrow{\mu_\alpha} Cte_H$, where $Cte_H$ is the constant functor and ${\mu_\alpha}$ the obvious N.T. But I just can't prove that the arrow $F(C) \rightarrow H$ is unique, which is the only missing condition.

Answer (score 2):

(I misread your question and wrote the answer about limits; but everything below holds with colimiting cocones in place of limiting cones).

Given a functor category $[\mathcal E,\mathcal C]$, a diagram $\mathcal D\xrightarrow{J}[\mathcal E,\mathcal C]$, and a limiting cone $F\overset{\phi_A}\Rightarrow JA$ over $J$, it is not in general true that for any object $X$ in $\mathcal E$, $F(X)\xrightarrow{\phi_{A,X}}JA(X)$ is a limiting cone for $\mathcal D\xrightarrow{J-(X)}\mathcal C$.

Rather, the conclusion you want can be proven if the limiting cones $F(X)\xrightarrow{\phi_{A,X}}JA(X)$ for $\mathcal D\xrightarrow{J-(X)}\mathcal C$ exist for every object $X$ in $\mathcal E$. Explicitly, fix a choice of such limiting cones for each object $X$. Then using the universal properties of all the limiting cones you can prove

1. the vertices $FX$ of those limiting cones extend to a functor $\mathcal E\xrightarrow{F}\mathcal C$ as follows. A morphism $X\xrightarrow{f} Y$, determines morphisms $JA(X)\xrightarrow{JA(f)}JA(Y)$, one for each $A$. If we compose them with the projection morphisms $FX\xrightarrow{\phi_{A,X}}JA(X)$ of the cone over $\mathcal D\xrightarrow{J-(X)}\mathcal C$, we will get morphisms$FX\xrightarrow{\phi_{A,X}}JA(X)\xrightarrow{JA(f)}JA(Y)$. These from a cone over $\mathcal D\xrightarrow{J-(Y)}$ because each $JA\overset{Ja}\Rightarrow JB$ for a morphism $A\xrightarrow{a}B$ in $\mathcal D$ is a natural transformation. Explicitly, in the diagrams 
   $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
   FX @>\phi_{A,X}>> JA(X) @>JA(f)>> JA(Y)\\
   @| @V(Ja)_XVV @V(Ja)_YVV\\
   FX @>\phi_{B,X}>> JB(X) @>JB(f)>> JB(Y)
   \end{CD}(1)$$
   the right square commutes by naturality of $JA\overset{Ja}\Rightarrow JB$, and the left square by $FX\xrightarrow{\phi_{A,X}}JA(X)$ being the projection morphisms of a cone. Hence the whole diagram commutes, so the composites $FX\xrightarrow{\phi_{A,X}}JA(X)\xrightarrow{JA(f)}JA(Y)$ are indeed the projection morphisms of a cone over $\mathcal D\xrightarrow{J-(Y)}\mathcal C$.
   Therefore, there must be a unique morphism $FX\xrightarrow{Ff}FY$ so that all the projections $FX\xrightarrow{\phi_{A,X}}JA(X)\xrightarrow{JA(f)}JA(Y)$ factor as $FX\xrightarrow{Ff}FY\xrightarrow{\phi_{A,Y}}JA(Y)$. In other words, a unique morphism $FX\xrightarrow{Ff}FY$ so that all the diagrams
   $$\begin{CD}
   FX @>\phi_{A,X}>> JA(X)\\
   @VFfVV @VJA(f)VV\\
   FY @>\phi_{A,Y}>> JA(Y)
   \end{CD}(2)$$ commute.
2. You should check that $FX\xrightarrow{F\mathrm{id}_X}FX$ is the identity morphism and that $FX\xrightarrow{Ff}FY\xrightarrow{Fg}FZ$ is $FX\xrightarrow{Fg\circ Ff}FZ$, i.e. that we have extended the choice of vertices of limiting cones $FX$ into a functor $\mathcal E\xrightarrow{F}\mathcal C$. Knowing the functor, since $FX\xrightarrow{Ff}FY$ were defined so that all all diagrams (2) commute, we can see that the projection morphisms $F(X)\xrightarrow{\phi_{A,X}}JX$ are the components of natural transformations $F\overset{\phi_A}\Rightarrow JA$.
3. The resulting collection of natural transformations $F\overset{\phi_A}\Rightarrow JA$, one for each $A$ in $\mathcal E$, is a cone over $\mathcal D\xrightarrow{J}[\mathcal E,\mathcal C]$. Indeed, for every morphism $A\xrightarrow{a}B$, the diagram
   $$\begin{CD}
   F @>\phi_A>> JA\\
   @| @VJaVV\\
   F @>\phi_B>> JB
   \end{CD}$$
   of natural transformations commutes because the left squares in diagrams (1) are the components of these natural transformations, and these commute.
4. It remains to check that the cone over $\mathcal D\xrightarrow{J}[\mathcal E,\mathcal C]$ given by the projection morphisms $F\overset{\phi_A}\Rightarrow JA$ is a limiting cone. Consider another cone cone over $\mathcal D\xrightarrow{J}[\mathcal E,\mathcal C]$ with projection morphisms $G\overset{\psi_A}\Rightarrow JA$. Then for each $X$ in $\mathcal E$, the components $GX\xrightarrow{\psi_{A,X}}JA(X)$ are themselves projection morphisms of a cone over $\mathcal D\xrightarrow{J-(X)}\mathcal C$ (evaluation at an object is functor). Since the $FX\xrightarrow{\phi_{A,X}}JA(X)$ were the projection morphisms of a limiting cone, it follows that there exist unique morphisms $GX\xrightarrow{\chi_X}FX$ so that $\psi_{X,A}=\phi_{X,A}\circ\chi_X$. In particular, if there were a natural transformation $G\Rightarrow F$ through which $G\overset{\psi_A}\Rightarrow JA$ factor as $G\Rightarrow F\overset{\phi_A}\Rightarrow JA$, its components would have to be the $GX\xrightarrow{\chi_X}FX$ we defined.
5. As soon as we check that $GX\xrightarrow{\chi_X}FX$ are the components of a natural transformation, we'll be done.
   Add these to diagrams (2), to obtain diagrams
   $$\begin{CD}
   GX @>\chi_X>> FX @>\phi_{A,X}>> JA(X)\\
   @VGfVV @VFfVV @VJB(f)VV\\
   GY @>\chi_Y>> FY @>\phi_{A,Y}>> JA(Y)
   \end{CD}$$
   The right square commutes because we have natural transformations $F\overset{\phi_A}\Rightarrow JA$, and the outer rectangle commutes because $GX\xrightarrow{\chi_X}FX\xrightarrow{\phi_{A,X}}JA(X)$ are the components of the natural transformation $G\overset{\psi_A}\Rightarrow JA$.
   It follows that the composites $\phi_{A,Y}\circ(Ff\circ\chi_X)$ and $\phi_{A,Y}\circ(\chi_Y\circ Gf)$ are equal for each object $Y$.
   Since $FY\xrightarrow{\phi_{A,Y}}JA(Y)$ are the projection morphisms of a limiting cone over $\mathcal D\xrightarrow{J-(Y)}\mathcal C$, by the uniqueness property of limits it follows that $\chi_Y\circ Gf$ and $Ff\circ\chi_X$ are the same morphism.

Note that since limiting cones are unique up to isomorphism, then if $F\overset{\phi_A}\Rightarrow JA$ is a limiting cone, it must be isomorphic to a limiting cone built out of a choice of limiting cones for the diagrams $\mathcal D\xrightarrow{J-X}\mathcal C$.

In particular, if $\mathcal C$ has all limits of diagrams of shape $\mathcal D$, the functor category $[\mathcal E,\mathcal C]$ also does, and the evaluation functors $[\mathcal E,\mathcal C]\xrightarrow{\mathrm{ev}_X}\mathcal C$ at object $X$ in $\mathcal E$ preserve those limits. More generally, the same argument works for arbitrary Kan extensions, not just limits.

Comment: I don't get it sorry :(. How can a vertex extend to a functor? Also how do you prove in the end that $F(C) = co\varinjlim_{\alpha\in \Gamma}    \ G_\alpha(C)$ ?

Comment: @Eli I added the details.